# Where can I find redshift data?

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, redshift, data

Is there any database for **redshift data of individual galaxies and stars** for a long period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Simbad](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fid), which is your one-stop comprehensive astronomy database. It includes redshift and other information for a vast number of astronomical objects.

Comment: This is what I need. But When I query it doesn't return the redshift values in query page http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fsam

Comment: Needed information is: coordinates of the object, distance, redshift and time

Comment: hm, works for me: http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=arcturus&NbIdent=1&Radius=2&Radius.unit=arcmin&submit=submit+id

Comment: Distance and time are not included. They are both important

Comment: distance you can easily calculate from redshift. and what time? time doesn't matter. it doesn't change for galaxies millions of years.